# Get sentiment score of emoji #Python

Tags: python, pandas, emoji, sentiment-analysis

```
df
0        NaN
1        NaN
2         
3        NaN
4          ❤
        ... 
26368    NaN
26369    NaN
26370    NaN
26371     
26372    NaN
Name: emojis, Length: 26373, dtype: object
```

From the df above, I would like to calculate the sentiment score of the emojis in each row.
If NaN, then return NaN.

```
#!pip install emosent-py
from emosent import get_emoji_sentiment_rank
def emoji_sentiment(text):
    return get_emoji_sentiment_rank(text)["sentiment_score"]

emoji_sentiment("")
--> 0.221
```

Applying to the whole column

```
df['emoji_sentiment'] = df['emojis'].apply(emoji_sentiment)
```

The code above returns `KeyError: nan`

Expected result:

```
          df             emoji_sentiment
0        NaN         |         NaN
1        NaN         |         NaN
2               |  (a decimal number)
3        NaN         |         NaN
4          ❤        |   (a decimal number)
        ... 
26368    NaN         |         NaN
26369    NaN         |         NaN
26370    NaN         |         NaN
26371            |   (a decimal number)
26372    NaN         |         NaN
```

Comment: *"The code above returns NaN for every row."* What happens if you remove the try-catch around? What's the exception that gets raised?

Comment: updated the code, I realized that the for loop won't work without using dictionaries, but now with `apply`, I am not sure how to revise the code.. @GPhilo

Comment: can you show us the whole error messege please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error, I'm guessing `get_emoji_sentiment_rank(text)["sentiment_score"]` fails if text is `NaN`, so you can either apply the function and assign the update only to the rows that re non-nan (preferable, but you first need to crate the column `emoji_sentiment` with a default `NaN` value):

```
df['emoji_sentiment'] = np.NaN # init the value for all rows
not_na_idx = ~df.emojis.isna()
df.loc[not_na_idx, 'emoji_sentiment'] = df.loc[not_na_idx, 'emojis'].apply(emoji_sentiment)
```

or you change the return of `emoji_sentiment()`:

```
def emoji_sentiment(text):
    return get_emoji_sentiment_rank(text)["sentiment_score"] if not pd.isna(text) else np.NaN
```

(uglier and less performant, but stll feasible)

Comment: Name: emojis, Length: 26373, dtype: bool, 'emojis')' is an invalid key

Comment: I missed a `.loc` in the `df.loc[not_na_idx, 'emoji_sentiment']` line, can you check again?

Comment: `KeyError: '\U0001f929\U0001f929'` It seems that the code works well if a row contains only one emoji, but it doesn't work if there are more than one emoji in a single cell. For example,  works, but  doesn't work.

Comment: That's a problem stemming from `get_emoji_sentiment_rank` (it's probably defined for single emojis and not generic strings of them), I can't help with that unfortunately, as it's an internal detail from `emosent`